# Getting ideavimrc shortcuts to work in visual mode with multiple lines selected

Tags: intellij-idea, vim, ideavim

I'm editing my .ideavimrc to emulate spacemacs-like key bindings in IdeaVim. This is working well for the most part, but when I try to apply this to a multi-line selection it just applies the action to the last line.

Minimal example:

```
let mapleader = " "
nmap <leader>cl    :action CommentByLineComment<CR>
vmap <leader>cl    :<Backspace><Backspace><Backspace><Backspace><Backspace>action CommentByLineComment<CR>
```

When I comment one line in insert mode it works great, but when I select several lines it just applies the comment to the last line. I assume it's losing the selection along the way, is there any way to get this to work?

Comment: Feel  free to create issue on YouTrack: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/VIM.

Comment: @y.bedrov I tried but can't. It does not let me assign the bug to a project but I can't submit a bug without project. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

That action isn't implemented by ideaVim, and is (I assume) unlikely to be implemented since IntelliJ already has this functionality.

Open "Preferences", select "Keymap" and search for "Comment with Line Comment", and set the hotkey to whatever you want. Admittedly, you'll have to use another keybind than `<leader>cl`, but this *does* work with multiple lines selected in visual mode.

If you require a vim solution, you'll have to vote for it on youtrack, as the commenter suggested.

Comment: I'm aware of IntelliJ's custom key mappings but it's not what I'm looking for. It's not great to have to memorize obscure key combinations and contort your hands to type them when you can just hit space and a mnemonic that does exactly what you want, is easier to remember and faster since you don't even have to take your hands off the home row. In any case IdeaVim has already implemented this with :action, it just apparently has a bug when you try to preform it on multiple lines and I didn't know if there was a workaround.